# Чтение двоичного файла

Tags: c++

есть файл fbx binarу. пытался считать с помощью ifstream но он считывает до определенного символа и дальше не читает файл(примерно 10 - 12 символ)

```
string line;
ifstream myfile("C:/Users/wARTEMw/Desktop/object/Blender_Binary.fbx");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (myfile.good())
    {
        getline(myfile, line);
        cout << line;
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ну кто же читает бинарный файл как текстовый...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно при открытии указать что файл должен читаться в бинарном режиме. Для этого используйте второй параметр конструктора:

```
ifstream myfile(
    "C:/Users/wARTEMw/Desktop/object/Blender_Binary.fbx",
    ifstream::in | ifstream::binary
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ifstream fs("C:/Users/wARTEMw/Desktop/object/Blender_Binary.fbx", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary );

// Узнаём размер файла
fs.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
std::size_t size = fs.tellg();
fs.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

// Читаем файл целиком
std::unique_ptr <char[]> buf;
buf.reset( new char[size] );
fs.read( buf.get(), size );

/*
либо без std::unique_ptr
char* buf = new char[size];
fs.read( buf, size );
и нужно не забыть освободить память delete []buf;
*/
```

когда нужно вывести все символы нужно учитывать что на вывод будут идти управляющие символы, то есть если попадётся '\0' то вывод прекратится

по этому если нужно вывести на экран или в файл содержимое, необходимо как то обозначить эти символы (на подобии как в Notepad++)

```
// примерно так
for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ){
    if( buf[ i ] == '\0' ) printf( "[NUL]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\1' ) printf( "[SOH]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\2' ) printf( "[STX]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\3' ) printf( "[ETX]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\4' ) printf( "[EOT]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\5' ) printf( "[ENQ]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\6' ) printf( "[ACK]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\7' ) printf( "[BEL]" );
    else if( buf[ i ] == '\n' ) printf( "\n" );
    else printf( "%c", buf[i] );

}
```